# detecting the current_page? in navigation partial dont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This is the code of 'shared/subnav' partial. When i click on a link it shows error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"location"}`
 but routes are defined. i think there is some problem in below code.

```
-if current_page? location_path
  = link_to 'Edit Location', edit_location_path
-if current_page? user_path
  = link_to 'Edit User', edit_user_path
-if current_page? alert_path
  = link_to 'Edit Alert', edit_alert_path
```

Here are my routes

```
location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)                        locations#show
user     GET    /users/:id(.:format)                            users#show
alert    GET    /alerts/:id(.:format)                           alerts#show
```

Comment: show your routes. `rake routes`

Comment: routes added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routes**

The bottom line is that since you're defining your routes as *member* routes, you need to ensure you are passing the appropriate *id* to each of them:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:show, :edit]
resources :locations, only: [:show, :edit]
resources :alerts, only: [:show, :edit]
```

This means you have to pass an `:id` value to any of these routes -- which can be done as follows:

```
user_path("2")
```

--

**Error**

The error is clearly being created here:

```
-if current_page? location_path
```

As mentioned above, you need to pass a valid "id" to the path, allowing it to pull the required object. You'll need to do the following:

```
-if current_page? location_path("2")
```

More pressing, though, are your individual calls to these methods. Surely there must be a better way to manage how this logic is defined. I would try the following:

--

**Helper**

I think I'd make a helper like this:

```
#app/helpers/your_helper.rb
Class YourHelper
   def edit_current(controller, object)
      current = controller.singularize
      return link_to "Edit #{current}", eval("edit_#{current}_path(object)")
   end
end
```

This should allow you to call:

```
<%= edit_current(controller_name, @user) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your routes, you don't have routes for `edit` actions of location, user and alert. You have routes for `show` actions, so add routes for `edit` for all the three entities and then you need to pass an object which you want to edit:

```
-if current_page? location_path
  = link_to 'Edit Location', edit_location_path(current_location)
-if current_page? user_path
  = link_to 'Edit User', edit_user_path(current_user)
-if current_page? alert_path
  = link_to 'Edit Alert', edit_alert_path(current_alert)
```

`current_location`, `current_user`, `current_alert` are the objects that you want to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your route helpers are defined, but are expecting an argument. For instance, `edit_user_path` is expecting to be passed a `user` object, so it knows which user you want to edit.

For users, you may be able to get away with something like `edit_user_path current_user`, but for other objects you will probably have to [pass them in to your partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

Answer (score 1):

Your show path also expecting some id value while comparing with current_page. have a look at below code this will solve your problem.

```
-if current_page? location_path(current_location or some id)
  = link_to 'Edit Location', edit_location_path(current_location or some id)
-if current_page? user_path(current_user or some id)
  = link_to 'Edit User', edit_user_path(current_user or some id)
-if current_page? alert_path(current_alert or some id)
  = link_to 'Edit Alert', edit_alert_path(current_alert or some id)
```