# Using 'current _page?' after AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using `current_page?` in my app. My code

Path: `groups/@group.id/`

```
<%- if current_page?("/groups/#{task.group.id}/") %>
  <a href="/tasks/<%=task.id%>/undone?idz=1" data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
<%- else %>
  <a href="/tasks/<%=task.id%>/undone?idz=2" data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
<% end %>
```

It does not work when I render a partial with AJAX. After a `PATCH` request, the `current_page?` doesn't recognize the current page.

Normally the good answer is if=true, and after rendering the same partial with AJAX, if becomes true. So I think the partial do not recognize the page anymore

Do you know a solution to solve that?

Comment: Define "doesn't recognize the current page"

Comment: I mean that after the ajax request, I'm rendering the same partial with this code above, and it's using the else of my condition instead the if

Comment: please, show the Rails log

Comment: there is no errors in the console, only on the path recognition

Comment: @stigGaret  It should work.Can u show what is coming in task.group.id and also  show what is coming in request.url or request.path.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240785/detecting-the-current-page-in-navigation-partial-dont-work